# Compiling Emacs from source on Ubuntu - problems with libxml2

Tags: compilation, eww

I'm trying to install Emacs 25.1.rc1 on Ubuntu 15.10, and have pre-installed the usual dependencies i.e.:

- `autoconf`
- `automake`
- `libtool`
- `texinfo`
- `build-essential`
- `xorg-dev`
- `libgtk2.0-dev`
- `libjpeg-dev`
- `libncurses5-dev`
- `libdbus-1-dev`
- `libgif-dev`
- `libtiff-dev`
- `libm17n-dev`
- `libpng12-dev`
- `librsvg2-dev`
- `libotf-dev`
- `libxml2-dev`

However, when I inspect the output of `./configure` libxml2/xml2 is off and when I `make && make install` emacs and run it, `M-x eww` says Emacs wasn't compiled with `libxml2`

I need help!

**UPDATE**

I had previously installed using Linuxbrew, which had installed `pkg-config` as a dependency. (ed. Yes, I know, well it seemed like a good idea at the time!)

Removed it and recompiled Emacs.  Configure finds and reports libxml2 as expected.

Comment: Try with `configure --with_xml2` and see if there is any errors in `config.log` about the said `xml2` libs. Otherwiae it should get enabled in configure's summary.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0` give ?

Comment: @politza `pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0            Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libxml-2.0' found`

Comment: @Lompik if you mean --with-xml2 I've already attempted that.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.

Comment: @politza I knew configure wasn't finding it already.  What I didn't know is why.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: What do you want us to do, remotely administrate your system ? Obviously that package is either not installed, not installed properly or in itself broken.  Does that file exist ? And if so, have you tried pdf-config's suggestion ?

Comment: See the update on the question. (Solved) The problem is pkg-config was installed in two locations.  Loving the sarcasm though, great feels for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was caused by `pkg-config` being installed in two places.  Once by apt, the other time by Linuxbrew.  The path was finding the Linuxbrew `pkg-config` copy first, which was configured to look in non-standard locations for libraries.

While this is problem is specific to the site,  it's important to note that `pkg-config` will report that a package isn't installed when it is (if it's not configured to look in the *right* place.)

**Tip:** always check the location of utilities (using `which`) to make sure the system is configured as you expect/assume.

Answer (score 3):

I've just solved the same problem, trying to install Emacs 25.1.rc1 on Ubuntu 15.10, by installing: `apt install libxml2-dev` before calling `./configure`.